# Javascript stopwatch timer is skipping the paused time while starting though the timer was stopped

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

Before making this question as duplicate by this tag "Javascript Stopwatch"; I would like to inform you that the problem is different from the others. Actually, I am building a javascript stopwatch to catch a task's duration. The problem with this stopwatch is while the stopwatch is stopped by clicking the stop button it stops the time; but while the timer is started again by clicking the start button, the timer just starts from the present time! The duration gap between the stop and start function has no effect on the timer. That makes the stop button useless. The timer should start from the exact stopped time.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="display-area">00:00:00.000</div>
<input id="stop_btn" type="button" value="stop" style="display: none;">
<input onclick="stop()" type="button" value="stop">
<input onclick="start()" type="button" value="start">
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
    var timer;
    var startTime;

    function start() {
        startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now());
        localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
        timer = setInterval(clockTick, 100);
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    function reset() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
        document.getElementById('display-area').innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
    }

    function clockTick() {
        var currentTime = Date.now(),
            timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - startTime),
            hours = timeElapsed.getUTCHours(),
            mins = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes(),
            secs = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds(),
            ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds(),
            display = document.getElementById("display-area");

        display.innerHTML =
            (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" +
            (mins > 9 ? mins : "0" + mins) + ":" +
            (secs > 9 ? secs : "0" + secs) + "." +
            (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
    };

    var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop_btn');

    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        stop();
    })
    start();
</script>
```

I understand that maybe the problem with this script is in the **clock tick** function wherein 2nd line the time is calculating by subtraction of current time and start time.

**clocktick function:**

```
var currentTime = Date.now(),
timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - startTime),
hours = timeElapsed.getUTCHours(),
mins = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes(),
secs = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds(),
ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds(),
display = document.getElementById("display-area");
```

so, the paused time needs to be calculated too and need to put in subtraction calculation as:

timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - pausedTime - startTime),

BUT I've no idea how to solve the issue. How can be the paused time calculated here?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to when you "stop" and create an `offline` variable that hold how long the timer is **no**t running, and subtract that in your `clockTick` method. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/2x5L8tqs/2/

Comment: Excuse me, but here is an another issue I am facing , the timer ignores the stopped duration while refreshing the page. Should I use some kind of cookie to solve this?